# ASP open dropdown from code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a drop down that will open using example code from.      https://jsfiddle.net/fz2sY/39/. 
However if I call the same function from code behind.
        `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "","runThis(dropdown);", true);`

The dropdown is inconsistant and opens sometimes but more often fails.
Is there anything that can be changed in the code behind to make the function call more reliable?

Comment: Change it to RegisterClientScriptBlock.

Comment: You're talking about a code behind - surely this is asp.net rather than classic asp

Comment: Sorry John, just edited that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `ShowDropdown` function after window load

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "","window.onload = function(){ showDropdown(document.getElementById('dropdown'));}", true);
```