# asp.net javascript from code behind with update panel

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

As a follow on from [ASP open dropdown from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098332/asp-open-dropdown-from-code-behind/30099834#30099834). I am dynamically creating a dropdown and putting into a updatepanel. The method

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "", "window.onload = function(){showDropdown(document.getElementById('ddl'));}", true);
```

The following code is not working as I expect. Does anyone know how to force a dropdown to open with a button when the dropdown is in an updatepanel?

Comment: Try This http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/723060/Open-javascript-alert-from-code-behind-in-update-p

Comment: Tried that but it doesn’t work in my situation. Thanks though.